# In Grover's Algorithm, is there a way to find 2-3 solutions with only 2 qubits?

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

I am currently learning grover's algorithm on qiskit(https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/grover.html). I notice that in the example of 2 qubits, we are looking for only one solution(|11>). Is there a way to modify the circuit so that we can find 2 or 3 solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking it is possible to modify Grover's search algorithm for problems that have multiple solutions. However, for 2 qubits it's not practical to do that. For 2 solutions, we get a problem in which exactly half of the search space are solutions, and no number of Grover's iterations will increase the probability of getting a solution when doing the measurement - it will always be 50%. For 3 solutions, solutions represent more than half of the search space, so the probability of getting a solution when doing the measurement will actually *decrease* when doing Grover's iterations.

If you want to explore the behavior of Grover's search algorithm for various search space sizes and solution numbers, [this tutorial](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumKatas/tree/main/tutorials/ExploringGroversAlgorithm) goes deeper into that, both with math and with visualizations of what's happening during the algorithm.